# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction / Cannot open connection

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, sessionfactory

In my application, I have a module that is designed to search a database for users and display their information in a table inside a jsp. I just setup Spring Security inside my application. I was able to make a connection to the database from the login page, though for some reason none of my DAO's CRUD operations (in this case, the search) are working.

Thanks, and please let me know if I can provide any more information.

**Here is most of my stack trace.**

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

...

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy8.searchEntity(Unknown Source)
    arlua.controller.SearchUserController.mySearchMethod(SearchUserController.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source

...

    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74)
        $Proxy14.getTransactionIsolation(Unknown Source)

...

    java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
        oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74)
        $Proxy14.getTransactionIsolation(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(DataSourceUtils.java:190)
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:508)
        org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        $Proxy8.searchEntity(Unknown Source)
        arlua.controller.SearchUserController.mySearchMethod(SearchUserController.java:35)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

**SearchUserController class**

```
package arlua.controller;

import java.util.List;

import arlua.dao.TableEntityFetchDao;
import arlua.exception.ImproperUserSearchException;
import arlua.exception.SearchStringTooShortException;
import arlua.helper.BuildUserTables;
import arlua.service.SearchCriteria;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class SearchUserController {

    private @Autowired @Qualifier("userInfoDaoImpl") TableEntityFetchDao userInfoDao;

    List<?> searchList;
    String error;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String mySearchMethod(@ModelAttribute("search_criteria") SearchCriteria search){

        error = "";
        try{
            if(search.getInput() != null)
                searchList = userInfoDao.searchEntity(search.getInput());
        }
        catch(SearchStringTooShortException e1){
            error = "Search criteria is too short. Be more specific.";
        }
        catch(ImproperUserSearchException e2){
            error = "Specify either an Id or first and last name.";
        }

        return "redirect:search_user";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/search_user")
    public ModelAndView mySuccessMethod(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("search_user");

        if(searchList != null){
            if(searchList.size() == 0)
                error = "Search returned no results.";
            else
                model.addObject("searchTable", BuildUserTables.buildSearch(searchList));
        }

        return model;
    }

}
```

**UserInfoDaoImpl class**

```
package arlua.dao.impl;

import arlua.dao.TableEntityFetchDao;
import arlua.exception.ImproperUserSearchException;
import arlua.exception.SearchStringTooShortException;
import arlua.tables.UserInfoTable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class UserInfoDaoImpl implements TableEntityFetchDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void saveEntity(Object userInfo) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save((UserInfoTable)userInfo);
    }

    public UserInfoTable getEntity(Object user_id) {
        return (UserInfoTable)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
            get(UserInfoTable.class, (String)user_id);
    }

    public void updateEntity(Object userInfo) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update((UserInfoTable)userInfo);
    }

    public void deleteEntity(Object userInfo) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete((UserInfoTable)userInfo);
    }

    public List<?> getAllEntities() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery
            ("FROM UserInfoTable").list();
    }

    public List<?> searchEntity(String search) throws SearchStringTooShortException, ImproperUserSearchException{
        //This search supports input of a user's seid OR a first and last name.
        if(search.length() < 3){
            throw new SearchStringTooShortException();
        }

        Session s = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<?> searchList = new ArrayList();

        //Searches for similar users with matching SEIDs.
        if(search.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")){
            searchList = s.createQuery
                //("FROM UserInfoTable").list();
                ("FROM UserInfoTable WHERE UPPER(user_id) LIKE UPPER('%" + search + "%')").list();

        }
        //Searches for similar users with a matching first and last name.
        //If the search contains more than 2 arguments, an exception will be thrown.
        else if(search.length() >= 3){
            String[] searchParts = search.split(" ");
            if(searchParts.length != 2)
                throw new ImproperUserSearchException();
            searchList = s.createQuery
                ("FROM UserInfoTable WHERE UPPER(first_name) LIKE UPPER('%" + searchParts[0] + "%') " +
                        "AND UPPER(last_name) LIKE UPPER('%" + searchParts[1] + "%')").list();
        }
        else{
            throw new ImproperUserSearchException();
        }

        return searchList;
    }
}
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="serverDatasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>url</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource" ref="serverDatasource"/>
        <property name="username"><value>unknown</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>unknown</value></property>
    </bean>

    <!--
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/mapping/user_info.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/mapping/login.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/mapping/linked_accounts.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/mapping/application_instance.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="serverDatasource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "userInfoDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.UserInfoDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "loginDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.LoginDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "linkedAccountsDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.LinkedAccountsDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "applicationInstanceDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.ApplicationInstanceDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "roleDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.RoleDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "applicationApprovalDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.ApplicationApprovalDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "userDaoImpl" class="arlua.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl"/>

    <!--  *************  TRANSACTION MANAGEMENT USING AOP **************** -->

    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>    
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allMethods" expression="execution(* arlua.dao.TableEntityFetchDao.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allMethods"/>
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="myTransactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="saveEntity"
                propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW"
                isolation = "READ_COMMITTED"
                rollback-for = "Exception"/>
            <tx:method name="updateEntity"
                propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW"
                isolation = "READ_COMMITTED"
                rollback-for = "Exception"/>
            <tx:method name="getEntity"
                propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW"
                isolation = "READ_COMMITTED"
                rollback-for = "Exception"/>
            <tx:method name="getAllEntities"
                propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW"
                isolation = "READ_COMMITTED"
                rollback-for = "Exception"/>
            <tx:method name="searchEntity"
                propagation = "REQUIRES_NEW"
                isolation = "READ_COMMITTED"
                rollback-for = "Exception"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you cut this down at all to only the relevant sections? This is far too long to have a good chance of getting any attention. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I removed the LoginController and security-context. On the same note, the exception itself originates from the SearchUserController on this line: **searchList = userInfoDao.searchEntity(search.getInput());**

Comment: Is

`<property name="url">
   <value>url</value>
</property>`
the right server url?!?

Comment: @Bellabax It is. In my actual xml file I have the real url. I just put a placeholder there when I posted it here. I've been able to successfully authenticate a db login in Spring Security with my url, username, and password from my login controller.

Comment: What happens if you mark SearchUserController as transactional. ... @Transactional public class SearchUserController ... ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call` means problem while connect to database do to URL/auth issues: looking stacktrace your are not getting connection via `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter` (your `id="datasource"`) but using `DriverManagerDataSource` (`id="serverDatasource"`): in few word your are trying to connect without using user/password.

In sessionFactory bean creating wire:
`<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>`
instead of:
`<property name="dataSource" ref="serverDatasource"/>`

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that when I was adding in Spring Security. I was authenticating with the UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter in my login controller, but my SessionFactory was using the DriverManagerDataSource.